# Cannot install jhipster-generator

Tags: node.js, jhipster, yarnpkg

I'm trying to follow the install guide on the jhipster website but i can't even run the first instruction, it keeps ETIMEDOUT'ing on me. I tred running it about 30 times now and it keeps failing (sometimes at different urls)

```
apixandru@DESKTOP-BAA6A1B MINGW64 ~
$ yarn global add generator-jhipster
yarn global v0.20.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning generator-jhipster > yo > fullname > npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/lodash: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.59.173:443".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\apixandru\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\config\\global\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.

apixandru@DESKTOP-BAA6A1B MINGW64 ~
$ yarn global add generator-jhipster
yarn global v0.20.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning generator-jhipster > yo > fullname > npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/js-yaml: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.59.173:443".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\apixandru\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\config\\global\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.

apixandru@DESKTOP-BAA6A1B MINGW64 ~
$ yarn global add generator-jhipster
yarn global v0.20.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning generator-jhipster > yo > fullname > npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/html-wiring: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.62.173:443".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\apixandru\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\config\\global\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

It looks like it starts making hundreds of get requests and eventually the server refuses to respond to me. I don't get why these responses aren't cached locally so i don't have to perform hundreds of requests every time i retry

https://paste.ubuntu.com/24048741/

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Can you access https://registry.yarnpkg.com/generator-jhipster from your browser? Have you tried installing jhipstrer using `npm install -g generator-jhipster`?

Comment: Also you need provide more information, do you have problems with other packages or just with this generator? Troubleshoot it a bit further.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I put a link in the original post with the full output of what is going on. It seems like it does start to make a lot of requests, but eventually the server hangs on me https://paste.ubuntu.com/24048741/

Comment: @GaëlMarziou it seems like npm install works but yarn doesn't. npm looks like it has retry logic implemented whereas yarn doesn't 

    "npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.112.162:443"

Comment: Have you tried suggested yarn option `--network-concurrency 1` mentioned in https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/944 ?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, I have, but i get the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error, in my case it it was only when trying to to `yarn add` from a Docker container.

Restarting Docker fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the registry correctly like:

```
npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org"
```